# Extract gurobi 3-dimensional variable value to a ndarray?

Tags: variables, optimization, gurobi

I have gruobio 3d-variables defined as:
self.r = self.model.addVars(self.noCells, self.noHours, self.noM, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='Renew_Charging')

need to retrieve the optimal values after optimization.

Tried code as below, the dimension is not correct.

```
Var = np.ndarray((self.noCells, self.noHours, self.noM))
for m in range(self.noM):
    for i in range(self.noCells):
        for j in range(self.noHours):
             names_to_retrieve = f"Renew_Charging[{i},{j},{m}]"
              Var[i, j, m] = self.model.getVarByName(names_to_retrieve).X
```

Q: How can get the values efficiently?

Thansk,in adviance